# How can I round an integer to the nearest 1000 in Pascal?

Tags: function, variables, integer, pascal, rounding

I've got a Integer variable in Pascal. Is there any possible function I can use that can round that value to the nearest 1000, for example:

`RoundTo(variable, 1000);`

Does anything of the sort exist? Or is there another method I should try using?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution for this kind of problem is to scale before and after rounding, e.g.

```
y = 1000 * ROUND(x / 1000);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for but just couldn't think of it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `RoundTo(variable, 3)`.

The second parameter specifies the digits you want to round to. Since you want to round to 1000 = 10<sup>3</sup> you need to specifiy `3`, not `1000`.

The [documentation for `RoundTo`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/Math.RoundTo) says:

> ```
> function RoundTo(const AValue: Extended; const ADigit: TRoundToEXRangeExtended): Extended;
> ```
>
> Rounds a floating-point value to a specified digit or power of ten using "Banker's rounding".
>
> ADigit indicates the power of ten to which you want AValue rounded. It can be any value from –37 to 37 (inclusive).
>
> The following examples illustrate the use of RoundTo:
>
> ```
> RoundTo(1234567, 3) = 1235000
> ```

*(I left out parts not relevant to your question)*

---

Side-note: `RoundTo` uses Banker's round, so `RoundTo(500, 3) = 0` and `RoundTo(1500, 3) = 2000`.

Comment: That's a Delphi-specific function though - it's not standard PASCAL ?

Comment: @PaulR, it's in `freepascal` as well, [`RoundTo`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/math/roundto.html).

Answer (score 0):

`x = 1000*(x/1000),` or `x = x - (x mod 1000)`

Comment: Both of the examples above truncate rather than round.