# Round / Truncate floating point numbers to N decimal places in Inno Setup Pascal Script

Tags: floating-point, integer, inno-setup, pascalscript

This does not look like Inno Setup question, but is actually related to its useful Pascal Script.

I wrote a code to do a floating point calculation.

```pascal
Height, DivisionOfHeightWidth, Width: Integer;

Height := 1080;
Width := 1920;

DivisionOfHeightWidth := Width / Height;
Log('The Division Of Height and Width: ' + IntToStr(DivisionOfHeightWidth));
```

Compiler log gives the output:

```
The Division Of Height and Width: 1
```

I want this compiler output to return this instead:

```
The Division Of Height and Width: 1.77
```

*I can't declare `Height` and `Width` as `Extended , Single` or `Double` as they are returning as `Integer` in most situations, so I need to convert those two Integers to two Singles.*

After doing it:

```pascal
Height, Width: Integer;
HeightF, WidthF, DivisionOfHeightWidthF: Single;

Height := 1080;
Width := 1920;

HeightF := Height;
WidthF := Width;
DivisionOfHeightWidthF := WidthF / HeightF;
Log('The Division Of Height and Width: ' + FloatToStr(DivisionOfHeightWidthF));
```

Compiler log now gives the output:

```
The Division Of Height and Width: 1.777777791023
```

But how can I get this output as `1.77`? **(Not `1.78` by Rounding)**
I mean how can I round this `1.777777791023` to two decimal places like `1.77`?

If rounding it like `1.77` is impossible to do, how can I round it like `1.78`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If rounding is acceptable, an easy solution is using the [`Format` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_format):

```pascal
var
  Height, Width: Integer;
  DivisionOfHeightWidthF: Single;
begin
  ...
  DivisionOfHeightWidthF := Single(Width) / Height;
  Log(Format('The Division Of Height and Width: %.2f', [DivisionOfHeightWidthF]));
end;
```

For details on the format string, see Delphi documentation for the [`Format` function](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Format).

Note that the `Format` uses a locale-specific number format (decimal separator particularly).

---

If you really need truncating, you need to implement it yourself like:

```pascal
var
  Height, Width: Integer;
  DivisionOfHeightWidthF: Single;
  S: string;
  P: Integer;
begin
  ...
  DivisionOfHeightWidthF := Single(Width) / Height;
  S := FloatToStr(DivisionOfHeightWidthF);
  P := Pos('.', S);
  if P < Length(S) - 2 then
  begin
    SetLength(S, P + 2);
  end;
  Log(S);
end;
```

---

*The above works in Unicode Inno Setup only as in Ansi version the `FloatToStr` uses locale-specific decimal separator, i.e. not always the `.`. In current Inno Setup 6, the Unicode version is the only version.*

Comment: I used your implementation instead of formatting String .It worked very well! Thank You!........ I am lucky as I always use Inno Setup Unicode Version..... ;)

Answer (score 1):

To truncate a value at the n<sup>th</sup> decimal digit simply multiply it by 10<sup>n</sup>, truncate the fractional part then divide by 10<sup>n</sup> again

```pascal
DivisionOfHeightWidthF := WidthF / HeightF;
DivisionOfHeightWidthF := Trunc(DivisionOfHeightWidthF*100.0)/100.0;
```

However one problem is that at the truncating step, values that are slightly lower than the integer value will be truncated further down, so you need to get the correct integer with `round()` before dividing

```
DivisionOfHeightWidthF := round(int(DivisionOfHeightWidthF*100.0)))/100.0;
```

Related: [How can I round an integer to the nearest 1000 in Pascal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15946123/995714)

Comment: This won't work, if the `1.77` is not representable with given floating point precision. So in particular it won't work with `Single`. You will get `1.769999980927`. It would work with `Double`. But even with `Double`, you may hit the same problem with different numbers.